# Change Master Page on per theme basis

Tags: sharepoint

I have designed a number of sharepoint (2007) themes, half of them use one MasterPage and the other half use another.

Is it possible to switch the Master Page based on the Theme in use?

Answer (score 0):

The source code for this [Master Page Picker](http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=SPMasterPicker) may be helpful.  This, combined with an understanding of the ASP.NET page/event lifecycle may be all you need.